# Disk Utility cannot detect a good portion of my storage space

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

While trying to set up Boot Camp, I received an error shortly after the process finished. Checking Disk Utility on both the software and Terminal, I was left with the space I set for my Boot Camp partition as unusable. I tried to delete/unmount/format/erase that partition but after multiple failed attempts I ended up just losing access to that space entirely. This happened twice, going from 500GB of usuable space to 250GB to 112GB. Below are screenshots from Terminal and the Disk Utility.

[image]

[image]

Below is the output from the command `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

[image]

How do I salvage this situation?

Comment: I don't know much about APFS, but it looks like your APFS container is too small (disk2). What happens if you try dragging those handles to make it bigger? (Try only moving the end one first; if you move the start it'll have to rearrange everything, and that takes _ages_.)

Comment: Also, what's in that first 8GB APFS container? I only have one.

Comment: Currently my disk utility only has one draggable handle, which is the one joining the free space and 8GB APFS container. Dragging it just adds to the free space. Both APFS containers don't seem to actually contain anything.

Comment: Also, random thought; would upgrading to mojave possibly help at all? just a sliver of a chance in any way

Comment: **Don't touch the second container!** (Unless you have a good backup.) It contains your entire boot partition and all its data. The 8GB one does appear to be empty.

Comment: I doubt upgrading to Mojave would help, although it probably wouldn't break anything. I'd hold off though, no sense trying to run an upgrade before we get this sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want find the free space, there is a third party utility that will show you were it went. This utility does not require installation or your password to use. You can find more information on this utility from the [driveinfo website](https://driveinfo.sourceforge.io).

Assume your downloads go to the default download folder. You and find the free space by downloading and entering the command given below.

```
~/Downloads/driveinfo-1.0.3/driveinfo -r disk0
```

An alternative to `driveinfo` command would be the macOS command given below.

```
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
```

To use the `gpt` command, you would need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

If you can post the output from either of these commands, then help could be provided on how to recover the missing space.

Comment: Why would you have to turn off SIP to use `gpt`? I certainly didn't on my external drive, and this would just be reading it.

Comment: The drive(s) that are part of the currently booted macOS are covered. You were not booted from the external drive, therefore the drive was not covered by SIP.

Comment: So it requires disabling SIP even to _read_ information? That's surprising.

Comment: Yosemite and earlier did not have SIP. El Capitan could read under SIP. Sierra and later can not. You can not even open with read and write turned off.

Comment: Here's the result of the 2nd command https://imgur.com/a/zRS9bm2